# Does Geofire give new keys to each user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, google-geolocation

I would like to use geofire for multiple location queries but don't know how to assign individual keys to each location. Does geofire automatically assign each user's location a different key?

Here is my Geofire code:

```
if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
 double latitude = gps.getLatitude(); 
 double longitude = gps.getLongitude(); 
 location.setText(latitude + "" + longitude); 
 //add points to database 
 myRef = database.getReference("Location"); 
 GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myRef); 
 geoFire.setLocation("Person", new GeoLocation(latitude,longitude)); 
} else { 
    gps.showSettingsAlert(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to update the key in firebase?

Comment: if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    location.setText(latitude + "" + longitude);
                    //add points to database
                    
                    myRef = database.getReference("Location");
                    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myRef);
                    geoFire.setLocation("Person", new GeoLocation(latitude,longitude));
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                } @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: I just want to know if geofire automatically gives new keys to each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is No. Geofire doesn't give you a key for each user. You must use your own logic to create a key and then add it to a list (I'll call this list `Locations`):

```
String key = //use your own logic to get this
if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
 double latitude = gps.getLatitude(); 
 double longitude = gps.getLongitude(); 
 location.setText(latitude + "" + longitude); 
 //add points to the list on the database
 myRef = database.getReference("Locations").child(key);
 GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myRef); 
 geoFire.setLocation("Person", new GeoLocation(latitude,longitude)); 
} else { 
    gps.showSettingsAlert(); 
}
```

If you're using Firebase Authentication, you can simply get the uid from the authenticated user and use it as your key.

Comment: Is there a way to get a data snapshot on data change?

Comment: I don't think I understood your question

Comment: That's great! Consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/364194) so that others know it has been solved.

Comment: Do you know how to geoquery multiple coordinates at once?